# Vector Valued Function Velocity and Acceleration

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$a(t)=2j-\frac{1}{t^2}k$$
particle movement is observed for t ≥ 1 second

v(1) = 2i+2j+k

r(1) = 3i-2j

I've encountered this kind of problem but all the problem I've encountered the t is $0$ so how can I can solve this problem ?

What I've tried is $$v(t) = \int 2j-\frac{1}{t^2}k$$
$$v(t) = (2t)j\space+\frac{1}{t}k\space+C$$
from what i know the C here is $v_0$ but what i have is v1 so how can i start to solve this problem ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: so i just make v(1) = c ?

Comment: please see the answer I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constant does not have to be the value at zero, it depends on where you integrate from. In this case, you start from $t=1$ and so that is your initial condition. Per your comment, notice that you are already given $v(1)$ in your problem. Compare it with your $v(t)$ obtained and deduce what $C$ should be.

Comment: can i make the $$C= 2i$$ so that the $$v(t) = 2i+(2t)j+\frac{1}{t}k$$

Comment: Right, you can recover $a(t)$ by taking derivative, and also it satisfies the initial condition you have.